# Can I use data annotations to specify an optional object property that has required properties?

Tags: data-annotations

I have a simple member registration data model with a few required properties and some optional properties. The BillToAddress property is optional.

```
public class MemberRegistration
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required.")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 7 characters.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private Address m_BillToAddress;
    public Address BillToAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_BillToAddress == null)
            {
                m_BillToAddress = new Address();
            }
            return m_BillToAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

If the user enters an optional bill to address, I would like the street, city, country, and postal code to be required. So I defined the Address data model, marking those properties as required.

```
public class Address
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Street Line 1 is required.")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    public string Street3 { get; set; }

    public string Street4 { get; set; }

    public string Street5 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State or Province is required.")]
    public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal Code is required.")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

But now the model validation fails when I don't supply a bill to address. How can I annotate my models so that the bill to address is optional, but *if it is supplied*, then it has to include street, city, country, and postal code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in MemberRegistration class. Because the BillToAddress property getter always returned a new, empty Address model, BillToAddress was never null and always correctly triggered the Address class validation. I changed BillToAddress to a simple auto-implemented property:

```
public Address BillToAddress { get; set; }
```

Now if I post a MemberRegistion without a BillToAddress, it passes validation because BillToAddress is an optional property.